# Getting reference locations from a project

Tags: c#, reflection, branch, .net-assembly

We have quite a big solution for one of our main systems, we are finally doing branching something which should of been done a long time ago but hey.

> - Main
>
>   - Development (New development)
>   - Service Pack (Bug fixing)
>
>     - Release (locked down, curently what is with the clients)

We have just got our main solution to the point where we have it bug free (Tested and signed off ready for clients) so this is the right time to get this in place. Our main solution however has something like this:

> - Main
>
>   - Project A
>
>     - Reference A (C:\DLLS)
>     - Reference B (C:\DLLS)
>     - Project B (Reference locally)
>   - Project B
>
>     - Reference A (C:\DLLS)
>     - Reference B (C:\DLLS)

Where we have directly relational projects they tend to be modules for our application and referenced locally (Project B). The external references are custom utility classes, which do not reside in the solution so are built and put in a folder (this is fine if we only have one solution not now we are considering branching).

> ### The Problem

The problem is now that I am branching, each branch will be refering to one section and the code can't be changed on a branch by branch basis. I want to be able to load the current `MAIN` and see what references it has and where they are located in the solution, I have tried to use `reflection` and `Assemblies` for the `MAIN.EXE` but that only gives the information of referenced .DLL's such as their name not where the project is expecting them to be. Then I moved on to looking at the `Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine`

```
  Project p = new Project();
  //This is the cs/vb project file
  p.Load(_projectPath);
  var v = p.Imports;
```

Which isn't the rightthing. Essentially I am trying to get a list of reference locations for a given project file, any possible suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: Why are your DLL located inside a specific folder and not copied to your Exe location on compile? Or why are you not creating a new folder to host your reference for each branch inside the Exe folder and something like Application.StartupPath + "\\DLLs"?

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras That's what I want to do, move all of the projects into the solution but I am not sure which projects are referenced where because it's so big, I have just took this mess and trying to clean up but I need to know where to clean up before I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was on to a winner by using `Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine` - each reference is a `BuildItem` and has `MetaData` called `HintPath` which gives what I need. To anybody who wants to try this:

```
  Project p = new Project();
  p.Load(_projectPath);
  var buildItems = p.ItemGroups.Cast<BuildItemGroup>().Where(x => x.Cast<BuildItem>().Any(y => y.Name.ToLower().Contains("reference"))).Select(x => x.Cast<BuildItem>()).ToList();
  var buildItemPaths = buildItems.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => y.GetMetadata("HintPath").ToString())).ToList<string>();
```

This gives me what I needed - hopefully helps somebody else too.